# date format in ms access

Tags: ms-access, date

How can I tell Access once & for all that I am in Belfast UK and not Belfast ME? To illustrate my problem, I have created a table containing the dates of each day in 2012. If I run this query

SELECT *
FROM tblListOfDays
WHERE dtmDay BETWEEN #01/05/2012# AND #31/05/2012#

148 rows are returned, all the dates from 5th January to 31st May. So Access is reading one date in US format, and the other (presumably because it is has no choice) as UK format. If I use

Format("01/05/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy")

instead of

## 01/05/2012

then I get the answer I want, but surely there is a simpler way than having to use Format all the time? All my regional/locale settings are UK as far as I can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [petr-abdulin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/735446/petr-abdulin)  said you can use

```
Format(expression, format)
```

So your code becam :

```
SELECT * FROM tblListOfDays WHERE Format(dtmDay, "dd-mm-yyyy") BETWEEN 
     Format("01/05/2012", "dd-mm-yyyy") AND Format("31/05/2012", "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

and dont forget to use format while inserting also.

and [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/format-function-HA001228839.aspx) you can find more info about this function.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no other way than to specify date format explicitly using `Format` function.